# stacked bar graph yAxis plotbands width is changing when toggle/add/remove the series dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

https://ibb.co/h7tmwtr
https://ibb.co/syRTyPG

for the first time i have given 5 plotbands and its fine and when i have added the series and removed/toggled the series on stacked bar graph plotbands width is incresing and need the same as in initial.
I dont want to chage the graph or plotband width.

here it is my code

```
chart.yAxis.plotBands = [];
            var compaserlen = chart.series.length - 1;
            chart.yAxis.tickInterval = 20 * compaserlen;
            var stfromval = 0;
            var sttoval = 20 * compaserlen;
            var colorstackplot = ['#D5D5D6', '#E0E1E1', '#EAEAEB', '#F5F5F6', '#F7F7F8'];
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                console.log("compaserlen", compaserlen);
            chart.yAxis.plotBands.push({
                    from: stfromval,
                    to: sttoval,
                    color: colorstackplot[i]
                });
                stfromval = sttoval;
                sttoval = sttoval + (20 * compaserlen);
            }
```

Comment: Hi @shirisha, Could you reproduce that problem in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: @ppotaczek thank you for your reply, simply what is the issue is for stacked graph i am toggle the series by visible false and true, if i toggle the switch visible is false and that is disabling in graph while disabling, graph yaxis plotbands are changing i just want to stable everything with disable

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable `ignoreHiddenSeries` property:

```
chart: {
    ignoreHiddenSeries: false
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hc40w59x/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.ignoreHiddenSeries

Comment: Thank you!! for response, but here it shows gaps in stcked graph i dont want to display the gaps if i toggle the series.

Comment: for example, https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/ in this graph if we toggle the legend if you observe plotbands are changing but i dont want to move only series should disable.

Comment: Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g2f41L3c/ Is that what you need?

Comment: yeah but here yAxis ticker values should update, like initially i have 1 series  at that time i  have [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100] are the yaxis values and again i have added the second series with updated values [0, 40 , 80, 120, 160, 200] like that ...
and if i toggle the legend again it should  update the yaxis vallues.

Comment: can you please help me here @ppotaczek
Thanks.

Comment: Ah, so you want to have fixed tick amount, right? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g2f41L3c/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shirisha_gunda/y7hepusg/6/  but if we toggle the BBB yAxis values are not changing and i need initial tick interval is 20 and based on series added that will be the double.

Comment: Please try to set `minTickInterval` property. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o05vkqmp/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, minTickInterval is not working for me.

Comment: Ok, so you need to use `tickPositioner`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner and define your own way of tick arrangement in the function.

Comment: i am not able to do tickPositioner, can you please gimme a help here.

Comment: Sure, just calculate tick positions based on your reqirements,  for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bcxkfemy/

Comment: but in this case when i am toggling the series, again yaxis plotbands are changing..

Comment: That  is just an example how to use `tickPositioner` function. You need to implement the required behavior by your own.